# Joomla! lightbox and Joomla! gallery

Tags: image, joomla, popup, lightbox, gallery

I'm looking for Joomla! image gallery that is simple to set up and has good customer support i.e. adding requested feature and fixing integration issue. No matter free or commercial, the only requirements are good looking user interface and very good support.

I want to be able to place single image with lightbox effect or create gallery of multiple images on my page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Phoca Gallery](http://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery) Component. It is a complete solution with component, modules and plugins which allows us to display images or Youtube videos in many different styles. It allows us to categorise images into Categories(like for articles) and each category can be shown as different album. It has support for many different type of lightbox, such as slimbox, highslide, etc.. but contains a "Powered by Phoca Gallery". You can enhance it even more by using custom plugins. I have used it on many sites, hope it'll help you. You can find it on Joomla extension site at-
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/3150

Answer (score 1):

you want open lightbox then dont need to download anything.

joomla provide simple technique.

include JHTML::_('behavior.modal');

and then pass class="modal" into the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should try [Art Sexy Lightbox](http://www.artetics.com/ARTools/art-sexylightbox) extension which is Joomla! image lightbox and gallery. It in the top of user ratings in Joomla! extensions directory which means it has strong support.

Art Sexy Lightbox has some nice features as various themes, ability to show images from local folder or Flickr or external pages, thumbnail auto-generation, etc.

From non-commercial galleries I would recomment CSS Gallery which is pure-CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ARI Fancybox](http://demo2.ari-soft.com/ari-fancybox.html) lightbox extension from ARI Soft team. This company provides different lightbox extensions and I suppose you can find an extension which is suitable for your requirements. I didn't have problems with support, support team responded to my requests very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at http://www.joomlaworks.gr/ Simple Image Gallery. Comes as a plugin, just drop it anywhere in an article, and point it to a folder in media manager and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

I use a free [Yoogallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/5362) plugin with thumbnail auto-generation and a possibility to change from lightbox to slideshow style.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MooBox Plugin from Vargas http://joomla.vargas.co.cr/es/documentation/15-miscellaneous/117-moobox-gallery works perfect.